# Error on Pushing to Github from SmartGitHg4: `current branch is behind`

Tags: github, push, smartgit

I get the following errors when pushing to github using SmartGitHg4. What should I do?

[image: Error on Push]

Comment: Other than exactly what that error is telling you to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run "git pull" as suggested by the message.

Not sure how you'd do this with SmartGitHg4.  But this should help: http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation.html?page=commands#pull